# Measuring the amount of photons

Tags: photons

Is there any possibility that we can measure the amount (number or quantity) of photons incident on a surface S? Secondly, if there's a constant source of light L, does the number of photons received by surface S remains constant throughout? In other words, does S ALWAYS receive N photons from L?

Answer (score 2):

There things called *photon number resolving detectors* (for example, the [EMCCD](http://www.emccd.com/what_is_emccd/)) that are to some extent able to determine the number of photons that are being detected. However, they only tend to work at the very low end of numbers of photons and even then there is a large uncertainty.

The number of photons that fall on a surface depends on the photon statistics of the source. Even for a constant source, the number of photons per unit time would fluctuate. So it is more a function of the type of light (thermal light or laser light) than of the surface on which it falls.

Comment: Thanks for the EMCCD info. Coming to the second part, assuming the source is thermal, can I say that the number of photons falling on S will NEVER be the same? In other words, if it's $N$ at time $t_{1}$, then it can be anything but $N$ at time $t_{2}$?

Comment: One can say that it is highly unlikely that number would be the same, but there is a small change that it could be the same.